# Tools for testing Functors, Applicatives and Monads?

Tags: haskell

I have created a type which implements Functor, Applicative and Monad. I wanted to verify that they follow the laws of each. But upon trying to do this manually, it turned into a daunting and quite difficult task.

So, what I am wondering is:

How can I automatically test that the laws of each class are properly implemented?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But upon trying to do this manually, it turned into a daunting and quite difficult task.

One way is to state your laws in a language like Coq and formally prove them. For example, John Wiegley proved [pipes law](https://github.com/jwiegley/coq-pipes) in Coq.

> How can I automatically test that the laws of each class are properly implemented?

You cannot get a strong guarantee unless you prove them. Maybe you can check their property using a library like [Quickcheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).

Comment: Maybe [liquidhaskell](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell/blob/61b4ab6d27b33c9579d58afaf815e34b92cc10b7/tests/equationalproofs/todo/MonadicLaws.hs) will be able to do that, too -- but I can't judge how far they are yet.